patchcmd from `etoolbox` won't adjust `\textheight` and `\oddsidemargin` based on page number
I was working with a document, where I needed to set a certain layout for certain pages. Here I've defined a layout where the top margin is 2in for the first 2 pages and 0.4in for pages > 2 and left margin of 0.4in for odd pages and 4.42in for even pages as an example.
The below code is something that I tried working with, but it only correctly applied the asked layout for \topmargin and nothing else (refer to the attached image).
Any help or related documents would be very useful.
Thanks!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\textwidth}{3.75in}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.6in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.94in}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\oddsidemargin}{\ifodd\count\z@ -.6in \else 3.42in \fi}{}{}
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\topmargin}{\ifnum\count\z@>2 -.6in \else 1in \fi}{}{}
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\textheight}{\ifnum\count\z@>2 10.94in \else 8.94in \fi}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}





If you'd use option twoside you'd not need to patch \oddsidemargin but could use \evensidemargin for even pages and \oddsidemargin for odd pages. Change of \textheight does not change internal lengths like \vsize. … You are already loading geometry, so why don't you use it?

@cabohah After setting \evensidemargin separately, it was causing some issues and the reason why I didn't use geometry package's default margins is because I need to set the margins dynamically, as I don't know what the total height of content inside would be. So creation of pages should trigger the page margin allocation.

geometry provides \newgeoemtry to change the margins inside the document. And "some issues" is not a sufficient problem description.

@cabohah \newgeometry works if I use a \newpage command which requires me to "know" where a new page will start, unfortunately for my use case, the content for the document is dynamic and I won't know after how much content would I like to place a new page. Therefore I needed an automatic trigger and the reason why I can't use the \newgeometry command. And for \evensidemargin, same issue of dynamic page content (granted the snippet that I provided  above mentions even, odd condition for the left margin, I need to know how to modify it for any condition, so my bad).

\textheight is a dimen register and you are replacing it by a literal, it is hard to guess the intention but it's never likely to have a good outcome.
The situation for \oddsidemargin is worse, \@outputpage has
         \let\@themargin\oddsidemargin

which defines \@themargin to be the dimen register \oddsidemargin but after your patch \@outputpage will have
         \let\@themargin\ifodd
         \count\z@ -.6in \else 3.42in \fi

which will define \@themargin to be the tex primitive \ifodd , then give a low level error assigning -.6 to \count0.

Could you please elaborate on what dimen registers are or provide some documentations to read?

Thanks!


@RohanGunjalZeenX1 well the texbook or tex-by-topic will explain registers, or any latex tutorial on \newlength but the same would apply to any programming language, if you have an integer variable n  you might be able to replace n in code by a literal 3  it might work eg to replace m=n by m=3 but usually it will fail eg code such as n=4 will just give syntax errors if you replace n by 3 and have 3=4  that is essentially what you are doing.

hmm, will look more into it, thanks for the help!

@RohanGunjalZeenX1 it is not clear what your main aim is, but the solution can not involve patching \@ouputpage even if you make it seem to work sometimes it is unsupported and could break at any package or latex update and is just highly unlikely to be needed.

Well, all I wan't is that the pages should dynamically set the margins based on page margin, i.e, whatever triggers the creation of pages internally, must allot the "new" margins. My input (such as \newpage or \clearpage) shouldn't be needed to apply the new changes to the page.

sorry I do not know what you mean by "set the margins based on page margin" as that seems circular, also note that there are only very limited ways that you can change the page margins mid document as you can not change the text width at an automatic page break, only at a forced break such as \clearpage

Sorry, I meant margins based on page number! But the above code works somehow for the \textheight change, although with a delay of one page (refer to the image attached, the condition says > 2 page number, but the new \textheight applies from 4th page onwards (+1 delay)).

yes changing textheight is far easier but changing textwidth (which is implied by changing the left margin unless you change the right margin by the opposite amount, is not possible.  Naturally you get a one page delay in the code you have as that is setting up the parameters for the following page,  but you are simply re-implementing the standard twoside option in an unsafe way, you should remove all these patches and use [twoside] @RohanGunjalZeenX1

yeah, implemented [twoside] for the left margin. thanks for the help!
